# In KOMA-Script, is there a way to apply \setkomafont (only) to the body of the text?

Tags: koma-script

I am using KOMA-Script (usually the `scrbook` class, but it doesn't matter). I am happy with the default, and only want to change the text body, as it were: Leaving footnotes, pagenumbers, captions, dispositions etc. alone.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or do I really have to go the other way, i.e. specify a default and then change everything else?

Comment: basically yes. dispositions use by default the sans serif family, so they won't be affected if you change \normalfont, but almost everything else is derived from it.

Comment: So I set `\normalfont`, and then change `author`, `caption`, `date`, `dedication`, `dictum`, `footnote`, `pagenumber`, `publishers` etc. etc. to something else, instead of the other way round? Doesn't seem very efficient to me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: well normally when you change the default font you want the other parts to switch with it. It would be highly inefficient if thousands of document would have to set the fonts for all these details one by one only because you want it the other way round.

Comment: I'm just saying KOMA should provide a way to change the appearance of regular, running-text paragraphs. You can change almost anything else, after all. But that's beyond the scope of tex.SE. Thanks for help.

Comment: hm. You mean KOMA should provide an option only for you? Be careful what you ask for, there is an option `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`, and perhaps you get an `ingmarwantshisownfontsetup`.

Comment: LOL ... I've seen that one. No, I don't want an option for myself, necessarily, I just find it hard to believe I am the first person ever to run into this. Well, I'll just have to work around it, I guess.